# How to fix vertical alignment of a minipage with a wrapfigure inside

Tags: vertical-alignment, minipage, wrapfigure

In this example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\begin{document}

foo \begin{minipage}[t]{.9\linewidth}
              \lipsum[1]
            \end{minipage}

bar  \begin{minipage}[t]{.9\linewidth}
              \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
                \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
              \end{wrapfigure}
              \lipsum[2]
            \end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

the vertical alignment of the first minipage is as requested, the first line of the `\lipsum` perfectly aligns with the outside `foo`.

In the second minipage however, the vertical alignment of the text is off. This is because the `wrapfigure` creates a baseline right at the top of the `minipage`, such that the location of the baseline of the first actual line is not available any more. This results in aligning the very top of the minipage with the baseline of `bar`.

Is there any way to either

1. restore that information

or

2. force the baseline of the first line to be a specific distance from the top of the minipage such that the minipage can be raised by that specific amount?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do the second option by inserting a strut and adjusting the minipage accordingly. The `adjustbox` package has everything available that is needed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newlength{\strutheight}

\begin{document}

  \settoheight{\strutheight}{\strut}

  foo \begin{minipage}[t]{.9\linewidth}
        \lipsum[1]
      \end{minipage}

  bar \begin{adjustbox}{valign=T,raise=\strutheight,minipage={.85\linewidth}}
        \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0pt}
          \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
        \end{wrapfigure}
        \strut \lipsum[2]
      \end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```