# Where does the space before wrapfigure comes from and how can it be eliminated?

Tags: spacing, wrapfigure

The following MWE's code (taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286619/112503) and slightly modified: added minipages around) should demonstrate the details:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz,wrapfig}

\setlength\intextsep{0pt}%<- doesn't seem to matter

\begin{document}
%
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}%
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}%
            \fill (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{wrapfigure}%

    \lipsum[1]%
\end{minipage}%
}%
%
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}%
%   \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}%
%       \begin{tikzpicture}%
%       \fill (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);%
%       \end{tikzpicture}%
%   \end{wrapfigure}%

    \lipsum[1]%
\end{minipage}%
}%
\end{document}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Question: How can the gap (see the red questionmark within the screenshot) be eliminated? (My build-environment: Win7-64, Texstudio, TexLive2017, LuaLatex)

**Update 1:**

According cfr's comments I've added fboxes around the minipages. This shows that there is no space added - instead the minipage environment seems to be influenced by wrapfig: Please see the following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: `\intextsep` certainly *matters*. Try setting it to `100pt`!

Comment: I don't think it inserts extra space. I think it alters the baseline. Try putting `\fbox`es around the `minipage`s to see what I mean. (Not sure about this, though.) `wrapfig` inserts a `\par` with an `\hrule`, I think, to set the width of the box to the required value. If you put a letter before the `wrapfig`, it is possibly a little clearer. The `\par` doesn't add any vertical space, but I think it changes the location of `t` relative to the `minipage`. However, I don't see why this should affect anything outside the box ....

Comment: In case it is useful, you don't get the same problem if you use coffins rather than mini-pages. However, mixing a coffin and a `wrapfig` is possibly not the best idea.

Comment: @cfr thanks for your analysis! I've addeed fboxes around and now I see: wrapfig influences the minipage. Should I update the question accordingly?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27699. Try \begingroup \setlength\intextsep{0pt} ... \endgroup

Comment: @Ross I already tried this, without success. The "possible duplicate" seems to be a duplicate of the question I've linked in my question.

Comment: You could do, yes. It might mean something to somebody. My default diagnostics in these kinds of cases is drawing around boxes. However, in this case, I still can't understand what's happening. I don't understand why `wrapfig` would be affecting stuff outside the `minipage` which contains it :(.

Comment: @cfr I just found a similar (I think not exactly duplicate) question. Adapting the  solution/workaround provided in the answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/309452/112503) using adjustbox makes the gap smaller (but negative) but does not eliminate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are top-aligning your minipages. If a minipage (or some other box) starts with normal text then "top-aligning" means that its baseline is at the baseline of the first text line. But if it starts with some \vspace then this determines the baseline.

Inside a minipage wrapfig adds at first a zero \vspace. The easiest way to "avoid" the gap is to add a similar space to the other minipage, to adjust their baseline in a similar way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\setlength\intextsep{0pt}
\begin{document}

\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.32\textwidth}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{2cm}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}%
            \fill (0, 0) rectangle (2, 2);%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{wrapfigure}%

    \lipsum[1]%
\end{minipage}%
}%
%
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.32\textwidth}%
\vspace{0pt}
    \lipsum[1]%
\end{minipage}%
}%
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.32\textwidth}%
    \lipsum[1]%
\end{minipage}%
}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you very much, especially for the explanation!

Comment: @yo' Yes a strut is probably not a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it ;)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,tikz,wrapfig}

\setlength\intextsep{-1.8pt}%<- doesn't seem to matter


\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}%
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}%
            \fill (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);%
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{wrapfigure}%
    \vspace*{-6.7pt}

    \lipsum[1]%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}%
%   \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{4cm}%
%       \begin{tikzpicture}%
%       \fill (0, 0) rectangle (4, 4);%
%       \end{tikzpicture}%
%   \end{wrapfigure}%

    \lipsum[1]%
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Just uploaded for you to see if you can figure out what that numbers needed are...

[image]

Comment: This does not really identify the problem and will, as you presumably know, be extremely fragile, breaking in all kinds of cases. I'd rather take my chances with a `wrapfigure` in a coffin, to be honest.

Comment: lol... I am not so good yet... I thought you may figure out something that I can not... Hahaha... Now I can't remove it... but may be try to find an equation giving the numbers till I die... lol

Comment: @koleygr Do you have any proposals for the equation?

Comment: @Léo Léopold Hertz 준영 I don't think I will find it in the next two or three years.... But if later I need this option and has still the bug... I will try :)

Answer (score 0):

Why use the boxes at all?
Is there an actual function in the environment for them?
If not, omit them: simple is best.
Employ vspace, within the wrapfig environment, with a positive or negative value, to raise or lower the level of the figure to match the level of the text.